# How to increment variables in JMeter and how to override values of user defined variables?

Tags: multithreading, apache, jmeter, load-testing, beanshell

I need to increment a variable for each thread.

Example:

Thread 1: $(Test_Var) should be 1001

Thread 2: $(Test_Var) should be 1002

Thread 3: $(Test_Var)) should be 1003 
and so on ..

In the test plan I defined some user defined variables. Here I set up one $(Start_Test_Var) with the value of 1000.

Now I am starting my test and it will always count until 1001 because the start value is set on 1000.

How can I increment the variable for each thread? I never pass the value of 1001 and I have no idea what to do.

JMeter always “remember” the start variable and starts to count from 1000 up but I want Jmeter to count up from the last value of the variable (1000, 1001, 1002).

I tried to set up a “SetUp”-Thread group with all settings and with all user defined variables. Then I added a BeanShell Assertion in my “real” thread group but it didn’t worked either.

Although my calculation works:

[Calculation of the variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzEQF.png)

Is there a way to override the value of the user defined variable?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

JMeter Variables are local to current Thread Group only, if you want to pass variables between Thread Groups you need to use JMeter Properties instead, i.e.

- [__setProperty() function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) in the setUp Thread Group to set the value
- [__P() function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) in "real" thread group to read the value

See [Knit One Pearl Two: How to Use Variables in Different Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups) article for more details.

Also be aware of [__counter() function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) which can produce "global" number which will increment by 1 each time this function is called.